# I am trying to join a URL in scrapy but unable to do so

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, data-science

I am trying to fetch (id and name)i.e name from one website and want to append the variable to another link. for eg in the name variable i get - /in/en/books/1446502-An-Exciting-Day.(There are many records) and then i want to append the name variable to 'https://www.storytel.com' to fetch data specific to the book. Also I want to put a condition for a_name i.e if response.css('span.expandAuthorName::text') is not available than put '-' else fetch the name.

```
import scrapy

class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'brickset-spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.storytel.com/in/en/categories/1-Children?pageNumber=100']

    def parse(self, response):
        # for quote in response.css('div.gridBookTitle'):
        #     item = {
        #         'name': quote.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        #     }
        #     yield item
        urls = response.css('div.gridBookTitle > a::attr(href)').extract()
        for url in urls:
            url = ['https://www.storytel.com'].urljoin(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        yield {
            'a_name': response.css('span.expandAuthorName::text').extract_first()
        }
```

I am trying to append "https://www.storytel.com".urljoin(url) but i am getting error for the same. Being new to scrapy I tried many thing but unable to resolve the issue. I am getting error - in line 15 list object has no attribute urljoin. Any leads on how to overcome this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with this solution.

```
for url in urls: 
  url = 'https://www.storytel.com'+ url 

  yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)
```

it helps let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```py
url = ['https://www.storytel.com'].urljoin(url)
```

Here you are trying to "join" a string to a *list* of strings. If you want to append a given url (which is a string) to the base string (https://etc...), you could do it by:

```py
full_url = "https://www.storytel.com".join(url)

# OR

full_url = "https://www.storytel.com" + url
```

You can check the docs about strings (specifically 'join') here: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

EDIT: also, I'm not sure that urljoin exists...

Comment: I tried the thing you mentioned already. It gives me a string of the url and that does not serve my purpose. Thanks for helping though!!!